# Download all the files from a s3 bucket using scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3

I tried the below code to download one file successfully but unable to download all the list of files

```
client.getObject(
new GetObjectRequest(bucketName, "TestFolder/TestSubfolder/Psalm/P.txt"),
new File("test.txt"))
```

Thanks in advance

Update
I tried the below code but getting list of directories ,I want list of files rather

```
val listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().
withBucketName("tivo-hadoop-dev").
withPrefix("prefix").
withDelimiter("/")
client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest).getCommonPrefixes
```

Comment: You need to try something before asking for help here. What have you tried to read all the files and what error you got ?

Comment: updated the qn with what i tried now can u please help @kannaiyan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple thing but I struggled like any thing before concluding below mentioned answer.
I found a java code and changed to scala accordingly and it worked

```
 val client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials)
         val listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest().
         withBucketName("bucket-name").
         withPrefix("path/of/dir").
         withDelimiter("/")

 var objects = client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
 do {
     for (objectSummary <- objects.getObjectSummaries()) {
         var key = objectSummary.getKey()
                 println(key)
                 var arr=key.split("/")
                 var file_name = arr(arr.length-1)
                 client.getObject(
                         new GetObjectRequest("bucket" , key),
                         new File("some/path/"+file_name))
     }
     objects = client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
 } while (objects.isTruncated())
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is fast and useful especially when you want to download all objects at a specific local directory. It maintains the files under the exact same s3 prefix hierarchy

```
val xferMgrForAws:TransferManager = TransferManagerBuilder.standard().withS3Client(awsS3Client).build();
var objectListing:ObjectListing = null;
objectListing = awsS3Client.listObjects(awsBucketName, prefix);
val summaries:java.util.List[S3ObjectSummary] = objectListing.getObjectSummaries();
if(summaries.size() > 0) {
  val xfer:MultipleFileDownload = xferMgrForAws.downloadDirectory(awsBucketName, prefix, new File(localDirPath));
  xfer.waitForCompletion();
  println("All files downloaded successfully!")
} else {
   println("No object present in the bucket !");
}
```